# How to get the list of git commands and the version they are introduced?

Tags: git, msysgit, changelog

Can anyone give me the list of git commands and the version they are introduced?

I'm going upgrade to git version 1.7.11

My colleagues are using version 1.7.3

I need to tell them what has been added/improved since version 1.7.3.

**NOTE:** we are using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
git help -a
```

This will give you the list of all git commands.

Changelogs with the information on new commands introduced and changes made to existing ones can be found at: http://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes
Just pick up the versions you need. These lists have exhaustive information on all the changes from release to release.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this location:
[git / Documentation / RelNotes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes)

Download all the release notes from 1.7.3 to whatever version you want to go to.

**IMPORTANT:** These will contain all the details, and not just new commands, but also bug fixes and incompatibilities, if any. *You will need all of these before you can safely decide you can actually make that upgrade.*

e.g.

```
Git v1.7.11 Release Notes
=========================

Updates since v1.7.10
---------------------

UI, Workflows & Features

 * A new mode for push, "simple", which is a cross between "current"
   and "upstream", has been introduced. "git push" without any refspec
   will push the current branch out to the same name at the remote
   repository only when it is set to track the branch with the same
   name over there.  The plan is to make this mode the new default
   value when push.default is not configured.

 * A couple of commands learned the "--column" option to produce
   columnar output.

 * A third-party tool "git subtree" is distributed in contrib/

 * A remote helper that acts as a proxy and caches ssl session for the
   https:// transport is added to the contrib/ area.

 * Error messages given when @{u} is used for a branch without its
   upstream configured have been clarified.
...
...
...
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: git subtree seems not to be available in msysgit 1.8.0.mssgit.0, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) for every version will give you the changes that were introduced at that version. You can figure out what commands were added between the two versions you're interested in from here.